# Improve script of setting height of div by comparing two heights

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a small script that compares the height of 2 divs and setting the height of the largest to another div.

My question is: **how to improve this script?**. Because I'm currently repeating the part of getting the hides of the 2 div's

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  showHeight($( "#tab-content2" ).height());
  showHeight($( "#tab-content1" ).height());
});
var bheight = 0;
function showHeight(height) {
  if( height > bheight){
    bheight = height;
    $("aside").height(bheight + 60);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select both of of them by selecting all IDs that start with `tab-content` and then loop over them with [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[id^='tab-content']").each(function(){
      showHeight($(this).height());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess kind of this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  showHeight("[id^='tab']"); // pass the selector
});


function showHeight(elem) {
   var heights = $(elem).map(function (){
      return $(this).height();
   }).get(), // loops through the selectors and gets the height in array

   maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights); // returns the max height value.
   $("aside").height(maxHeight + 60); // and set it here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some class to your tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bheight = 0; 
    $('.tabClass').each(function () {
        bheaight = Math.max(bheight, $(this).height());
    });
    $('aside').height(bheight + 60);
});
```